# "Plots" and "Viewer" panes not working in RMarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

When using RMarkdown, none of my plots or tables show up in the "Plots" or "Viewer" pane in the bottom right window.  If I enter the code into an RScript or the console however, they do appear.  For example, if I would enter this code:

```
iris %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Sepal.Width, y = Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_point()
```

into an RMarkdown chunk, the Plots pane would remain blank, while if I enter the same code in the console or into an RScript, the correct scatterplot appears in the Plots pane.  I have already tried updating both R and RStudio to no avail.  Why is this occurring and how do I fix it?  Thanks.

Comment: Usually, Rmarkdown plots appear just below the chunck when you run it manually, not in the Plots pane.

Comment: Rmarkdown is more for rendering to HTML or PDF, like Waldi said, Rmarkdown is like the R Studio notebooks when it comes to only running a selected like that produces a graphic